# Get Value of Selected rowwidget on ExtJS

Tags: extjs

How do I get the value of the selected row in rowwidget after the toggle. Please assist, I have tried the the bind functionality but it does not work or necessary for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if as you said row is selected then this must work: yourGrid.getSelection()[0]